# regular expression not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with JavaScript Regular Expression. I have test it on this website and it's working fine - http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm .

```
     var str = "Stalowa Wola;Nisko;Rzeszow";
     var re = new RegExp("Stalowa Wola[a-zA-Z\W]*Rzeszow", "i");
     var myArray = str.match(re);
     console.log(myArray);
```

But when I trying to run this code on my website, it's not working.Console return 'null' and I don't know why. I noticed that when i remove 'Rzeszow' from RegExp it's starts working.

Comment: But what do you need to match with it?

Comment: What is the expected result??

Comment: Are you aware that `[a-zA-Z\W]*` (if you escape the backslash correctly) matches everything except ASCII digits and the underscore, i.e. it's the same as `[^0-9_]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Stalowa Wola;Nisko;Rzeszow";
var re = new RegExp("Stalowa Wola[a-zA-Z\\W]*Rzeszow", "i");
var myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
```

You need to escape the backslash.

Alternatively use this notation:

```
var str = "Stalowa Wola;Nisko;Rzeszow";
var re = /Stalowa Wola[a-zA-Z\W]*Rzeszow/i;
var myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
```

The downside is that you must know the structure of the regex before runtime.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me. I think I have still much to learn about RegExp.

Comment: It's a bit different in javascript. Notably the exec method needs to be called in a while loop until `null` is returned to get all matches.